# Removing hover effect on a list of items in gwt

Tags: listview, gwt, gxt

I have a list of strings which are stored in a GXT ListView. I need to remove on Hover effect on the list of items because i don't have any use of hover.
Is there any solution to remove the hover effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duplicate of [How to remove hover style for ListView rows?](http://In%20your%20ListView.Resources,%20override%20the%20ItemBackgroundHover%20brush%20resource:%20%20%3CSolidColorBrush%20x:Key=%22ItemBackgroundHover%22%20Color=%22Transparent%22%20/%3E)
Anyway:

> In your `ListView.Resources`, override the `ItemBackgroundHover` brush
>   resource:
>
> `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemBackgroundHover" Color="Transparent" />`